# How to integrate MouseWithFingerprint app into windows WBF framework?

Tags: c#, windows

I have Secugen Mouse with Fingerprintsensor application / SDK, I can
enroll, and verify the enrolled finger using that SDK.

Now,

**I want to use this MouseFingerprint application / SDK as Windows login credential. How can i do this in windows 7 64 bit OS.**

If any information missing here, please mention in command area I will update.

Thanks.

Note :

> I am new to this stackoverflow, if my question editing is bad please
>   correct it.

Comment: Did you try  anything?

Comment: I dont't know what to try Next,   but I have a working SdK which can enroll user finger print and can verify the same and store into local ms access DB. Now i want to integrate this SDK into Windows 7 64 bit OS as a login credential Since device is fingerprint enable Mouse  .

Comment: @All,  Is there anyone can tell us how to intergrate or work with Windows WBF ?